# Jquery Cycle. Prohibit click while transition is running

Tags: jquery, event-handling, transition

How do i restrict clicking on next button, so it prevents from extra transition? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set a global flag to indicate a transaction is occurring.

```
var transaction = false;

$('button').click(function(){
  if(transaction) return false;
  transaction = true;
  $.ajax(...., function(){
    transaction = false;
  });
});
```

Comment: That looks great, but I cannot find click event in this stupid cycle plugin. Have you ever worked with it?

Comment: I found these options for a plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html. Probably we can use some of the options to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the event
2. Do Transition
3. Add the event